# Two second-order nonlinear differential equations.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system

I have a system of two 2'nd order nonlinear DE's, although I'm quite stuck with them. These are supposed to be geodesic equations for a cone. I've computed the Christoffel symbols, plugged them into the geodesic equation and got this. So the DE system is:

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\lambda^2}-\frac{u}{2}\frac{dv}{d\lambda}\frac{dv}{d\lambda}=0$$

$$\frac{d^2v}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{d\lambda}\frac{dv}{d\lambda}=0$$

Comment: Is there a typo in the second DE ? $v$ does not appear in it

Comment: Then, @JJacquelin gave the answer.

Comment: Actually there is a typo, I've changed the equations a bit, now both $u$ and $v$ appear in each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\lambda^2}-u\frac{du}{d\lambda}\frac{du}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$\frac{\frac{d^2u}{d\lambda^2}}{\frac{du}{d\lambda}}=u\frac{du}{d\lambda}$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{du}{d\lambda}\right|=\frac12 u^2+\text{constant}$$
$$e^{u^2/2}du=c_1d\lambda$$
$$\int e^{u^2/2}du=c_1 \lambda+c_2$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{erfi}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right)=c_1 \lambda+c_2$$
Fonction erfi : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html
$$\boxed{u=\sqrt{2}\:\text{erfi}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} (c_1\lambda+c_2\right)}$$

$$\frac{d^2v}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{2}{u}\frac{du}{d\lambda}\frac{dv}{d\lambda}=0$$
$$\frac{\frac{d^2v}{d\lambda^2}}{\frac{dv}{d\lambda}}=-\frac{2}{u}\frac{du}{d\lambda}$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{dv}{d\lambda}\right|=-2\ln|u|+\text{constant}$$
$$\frac{dv}{d\lambda}=c_3\frac{1}{u^2}$$
$$v=c_3\int \frac{d\lambda}{u^2}+c_4$$
$$v=c_3\int \frac{d\lambda}{\left( \sqrt{2}\:\text{erfi}^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} (c_1\lambda+c_2\right)\right)^2}+c_4$$
There is no closed form for this integral in terms of a finite number of standard functions.

If this problem is an academic exercise probably there is a typo in the wording of the question.

If this problem comes from applied sciences or technology solve it thanks to numerical methods of calculus.

Comment: Hi Claude ! Glad to meet you again. Well I'm getting old too but it's still okay. I wish you an happy end of year.